# IComparer did not return zero when Array.Sort called x.CompareTo(x)

Tags: .net, asp.net, sorting, icomparer

I've implemented an IComparer to sort results on a search page. Sometimes, in production, users are getting this error. All the data for the search (criteria, paging, sorting) is on the querystring, and I'm using the ELMAH library, so I can see the details in the email report of the error. If I copy the querystring from the user who got the error into my browser, the page works just fine. So it's sort of non-deterministic, apparently.

This is my Comparer:

```
Public Class ReverseDateComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of Promotion)

    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Promotion, ByVal y As Promotion) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of Promotion).Compare
        If y.ExpirationDate = x.ExpirationDate Then
            Return x.PlainTitle.CompareTo(y.PlainTitle)
        Else
            Return y.ExpirationDate.CompareTo(x.ExpirationDate)
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

So basically, sort by expiration date descending, then by title ascending. Is there anything obviously wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too sure about the  `y.ExpirationDate = x.ExpirationDate`. Try

```
Public Class ReverseDateComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of Promotion)

    Public Function Compare(x As Promotion, y As Promotion) As Integer
        Dim c As Integer = x.ExpirationDate.CompareTo(y.ExpirationDate)
        If c = 0 Then
            Return x.PlainTitle.CompareTo(y.PlainTitle)
        Else
            Return c
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply return 0 if x is y.

```
Public Class ReverseDateComparer
Implements IComparer(Of Promotion)

Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Promotion, ByVal y As Promotion) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of Promotion).Compare
    If x is y Then
        Return 0
    ElseIf y.ExpirationDate = x.ExpirationDate Then
        Return x.PlainTitle.CompareTo(y.PlainTitle)
    Else
        Return y.ExpirationDate.CompareTo(x.ExpirationDate)
    End If
End Function
```

End Class